# How to make Hammerspoon resize windows smoothly on OSX?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I'm using [Hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon) to resize my windows on OSX. Particularly, I want to be able to make windows take up half the screen, either vertically or horizontally, as well as take up the entire screen.
However, there is major redrawing lag when I switch between axes (e.g. vertical to horizontal). Previously I've used [Spectacle](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle), which performs the same task snappily.

To demonstrate, here are short clips of me resizing windows in Hammerspoon vs Spectacle.
Hammerspoon - *dead link*
Spectacle - *dead link*

Is this a limitation of how Hammerspoon resizes windows or could I optimize my config better?

Here's my `init.lua`

```
--
-- Window management
--
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "Left", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local max = win:screen():frame()

  f.x = max.x
  f.y = max.y
  f.w = max.w / 2
  f.h = max.h
  win:setFrame(f)
end)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "Right", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local max = win:screen():frame()

  f.x = max.w / 2
  f.y = max.y
  f.w = max.w / 2
  f.h = max.h
  win:setFrame(f)
end)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "Up", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local max = win:screen():frame()

  f.x = max.x
  f.y = max.y
  f.w = max.w
  f.h = max.h / 2
  win:setFrame(f)
end)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "Down", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local max = win:screen():frame()

  f.x = max.x
  f.y = max.h / 2
  f.w = max.w
  f.h = max.h / 2
  win:setFrame(f)
end)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "f", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local max = win:screen():frame()

  f.x = max.x
  f.y = max.y
  f.w = max.w
  f.h = max.h
  win:setFrame(f)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have window animation turned on,
you can turn it off with `hs.window.animationDuration = 0`

http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.html#animationDuration

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is good (the default animationDuration value is 0.2), but you will be changing a global value. Locally, instead of win:setFrame(f) you can do

```
win:setFrame(f, 0)
```

it will have the same effect.